# Change Cordova project android package name

Tags: android, cordova, package, rename

Does any of you know how to change the package name of an android project build with cordova?

I've tried to change the android project name by doing:

1. Removing the android platform from the project by executing `cordova platform remove android`
2. I changed the `<widget id>` in **config.xml**:

From

```
<widget id="com.oldName.oldName" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

to

```
<widget id="com.newName.newName" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

3. Reinstall android platform by doing `cordova platform add android`

Problem is that after I did it, I got an error when executing `cordova run android`:

```
(node:xxxxx) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'manifest' of undefined
```

***The only way to get rid of this error is to revert back to its original package name (and of course to re-install android platform)***

I tried to google a lot but I just can't seem to find any solution that works for me. Will any of you be kind enough to enlighten me on this?

Comment: You build your project correctly along with renaming the package-name (I just testet it). The errors occurs because of a failed assertion while your app is being started. This assertion seems to rely on your old-package-name but without the asseration-code its hard to tell.

Comment: @Blauharley

Thanks a lot for the reply mate. Hmmm, you think it's already correct? I tried to do it multiple times and tried many ways to fix it but it always produces the same error. 

Here's what I'm going to do, I'm going to ty renaming the package name in Android Studio instead, see if it works. 

Cheers mate,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `android-packageName` inside the widget tag

```
<widget id="com.oldName.oldName" android-packageName="com.newName.newName" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: Dude...., OMG it actually works! I've been trying to find a solution for this for such a long time and I couldn't find anything. I must've missed it in the documentation or something or maybe I haven't dug deep enough but wow, it's THAT simple? Damn... 

Thanks a bunch man, you're a life saver.

Comment: when i build the project, which id take the apk ? the id or android-packageName, i mean if the app in playstore already published using id and i add android-packageName to config.xml with new name can i republish the apk on same app

Comment: No, the id is the package name, but this allows to use one id for ios and another one for Android, but once you publish the id/package name can't be changed

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the old package with a new package by replacing new package in the entire source code, then renaming the folder in the main/java directory according to the new package.